# Chrome app does not receive outside UDP data in background.js until a window is created

Tags: javascript, network-programming, udp, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

The app I'm trying to create for the Chromebook (Chrome OS 60.0.3112.114 64bits) listens for UDP broadcasts and when such messages arrive I want it to open a window. So far so good and everything works when the JS is added to a window, but the point of the app is to be quiet listening to the messages and only after receiving a message it will open the window.

All code was moved to background.js and now it never receives the ouside message. The first thing that comes to mind is that it is being suspended so I added a setInterval in background.js to send data to myself simulating the external data arrival and these messages are received correctly, the script is not sleeping. The magic starts when I create any sort of window, instantly I start receiving the broadcasts. And as soon as I close the window the outside data is interrupted, I still get all my own messages sent from the setInterval.

Is there any solution to this? The next thing I tried to do was to create a hidden window but there is no such thing, also tried to use a background.html and putting an iframe inside with the background.js code will result in the same behavior.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "UDP Sample",
  "description": "Can't receive data",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    }
  },

  "icons": {
    "16": "calculator-16.png",
    "128": "calculator-128.png"
  },

  "sockets": {
      "udp": {
        "send": "*",
        "bind": "0.0.0.0:13000"
      }
  },
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(StartApp);

var socketId;

function StartApp()
{
  console.log('app started');

  chrome.sockets.udp.onReceive.addListener(SockRecv);
  chrome.sockets.udp.onReceiveError.addListener(SockError);

  SockBind(AppReady, AppError);
}

function AppReady()
{
  setInterval(function()
  {
    console.log("self sending data");

    var buf = new Uint8Array([70, 73, 82, 69]);
    SockSend(false, buf.buffer);
  }, 4000);

  console.log('listening for net events.');
}

function AppError()
{
  console.log('bind failed, retrying in 10 seconds.');
  setTimeout(StartApp, 10000);
}

function LaunchWindow()
{
  chrome.app.window.create('about.html', 
  {
    frame: "none",
    resizable: false,
    outerBounds: {
      'width': 400,
      'height': 300
    }
  });
}

function SockRecv(info)
{
  console.log("data received " + info.remoteAddress + " bytes");

  if (info.socketId !== socketId || info.remoteAddress == '127.0.0.1')
    return;

  LaunchWindow();
}

function SockSend(ip,data)
{
  chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, data, '127.0.0.1', 13000, function()
  {
    console.log("data sent");
  });
}

function SockError(info)
{
  console.log("something bad happened");
  if (info.socketId !== socketId)
    return;

  chrome.sockets.udp.setPaused(socketId, false, function(){});
}

function SockBind(ready_func, error_func)
{
  // Create the Socket
  chrome.sockets.udp.create({persistent: true},
  function(socketInfo)
  {
    console.log("new socket created");
    socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
    try
    {
      chrome.sockets.udp.bind(socketId, "0.0.0.0", 13000, function(result)
      {
        if (result < 0)
        {
          result = socketId;
          socketId = false;
          chrome.sockets.udp.close(result, error_func);
        }
        else
          ready_func();
      });
    }
    catch(err)
    {
      error_func();
    }
  });
}
```

Console debug (I manually executed the function LaunchWindow and suddenly outside data arrives):

```
background.js:7 app started
background.js:80 new socket created
background.js:25 listening for net events.
background.js:19 self sending data
background.js:61 data sent
background.js:49 data received 127.0.0.1 bytes
background.js:19 self sending data
background.js:61 data sent
background.js:49 data received 127.0.0.1 bytes
background.js:19 self sending data
background.js:61 data sent
background.js:49 data received 127.0.0.1 bytes
LaunchWindow()
undefined
background.js:49 data received 192.168.1.49 bytes
background.js:19 self sending data
background.js:61 data sent
background.js:49 data received 127.0.0.1 bytes
background.js:49 data received 192.168.1.49 bytes
background.js:19 self sending data
background.js:61 data sent
background.js:49 data received 127.0.0.1 bytes
background.js:49 data received 192.168.1.49 bytes
background.js:19 self sending data
```

Output of netstat -l proving the socket is waiting data:

```
chronos@localhost / $ netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:13000           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:bootpc          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:mdns            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:mdns            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug with `"persistent": false` - theoretically it should keep the background page running if there are active listeners. Switch to `"persistent": true`.

Comment: It does not work, when switching to true the app no longer loads:
Invalid value for 'app.background.persistent'. Packaged apps do not support persistent background pages and must use event pages.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then try reporting on https://crbug.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try that while waiting for parallel answers here.

Comment: If you haven't done so, please try [converting background page to event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#transition).

Answer (score 0):

ChromeOS has a firewall that prevents listening sockets from accepting new connections if there are no active app windows.

The best solution, I have found, is to create a `panel` type window, which is not hidden, but minimized. You can see an example implementation with https://github.com/kzahel/connection-forwarder or view a demo in the webstore: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/connection-forwarder/ahaijnonphgkgnkbklchdhclailflinn

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that and thanks for the explanation about the firewall thing, that makes some sense.